# How to fixed the Columnsize

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I have a problem with my result set. I can't get a fixed length of the columns.

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int cols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
for(int i=1; i<=cols; i++)
    System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i)+"\t");
System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------");
while(rs.next())
{

    for(int i=1; i<=cols; i++)
        System.out.print(rs.getString(i)+"\t");

    System.out.println();
}
```

The table look like this

http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=bf21f6-1527061884.png "Table"

The Column name aren't exactly with the data.

Comment: You mean in console (I don't open external links) ?

Comment: Yes in the console. The Column name are not exactly above the data. Its looks like it is moved to the left a little bit. Imgur is blocked in my Company bilder upload is just a picture upload site.

Comment: You can't expect to use a `tab` and have a correct alignment because `\t` will just push to to next "column" where each column is a length of 8 (hard to explain...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use print with format (adjust to desired length):

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int cols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
//format begins after 20 characters.

String format = "%-20s";

for(int i=1; i<=cols; i++)
    System.out.printf(format, rsmd.getColumnLabel(i));
System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------");
while(rs.next())
{

    for(int i=1; i<=cols; i++)
        System.out.printf(format, rs.getString(i));

    System.out.println();
}
```

For example:

```
public class FixedColumn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] test = {"13333","2qweqwe","3dddd"};
        String[] test2 = {"dsds4","6","6e"};
        String format = "%-20s";        
        for (String s : test) {
            System.out.printf(format, s);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (String s : test2) {
            System.out.printf(format, s);
        }

    }

}
```

Would return:

[image]

Comment: Note that this will work until a value is bigger than 20 character ;)

Comment: Yes. It's commented

Comment: No it is not... or you don't get my point.

Comment: For me it works i changed in to 40 but it works perfectly